# should i block all ping requests?

Tags: networking, security, iptables, ping

My intention is seek for protection, no needed to be a server, so i whant to avoid all kinds of SSDP, i've found some codes and need to know if its enough or too much:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p icmp -j DROP

iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j DROP 

iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP

iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j DROP

iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP

iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j DROP

iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j DROP

iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p icmp -j DROP

iptables -I OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j DROP

iptables -I OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP

iptables -I OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j DROP 

iptables -I OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP 

iptables -I OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j DROP

iptables -I OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j DROP
```

I've heard about tables mangle and raw, should i use them too?

Comment: Why not just deny all traffic you don't trust to your server?  SSDP and service discovery happen on *all* ports not just with PINGs.  It's far simpler and more secure to *deny* all traffic and only *allow* the traffic you want to allow than the inverse.  You don't need mangle, RAW, or NAT to block the traffic either

Comment: change the policy, right? its also block ping and SSDP traffics? sometimes i need to connect to publics wifi networks, so just want to get best protection

Comment: I posted a very simple starting point iptables rule set for a question a couple of years ago. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368071/iptables-that-only-allow-incoming-traffic-to-openssh-and-block-all-other-traffic).

Comment: Thanks Man, im gonna try this

Comment: You should not block PING requests. Ping is an important IP diagnostic tool that transmits no data (unless it's misused, but that takes both ends). Since you're not a server, it's unlikely you'll receive a "Ping of Death" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_of_death packet, and still more unlikely that it will make you sick.